# Error while using Cloudwatch GetMetricWidgetImage API in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I am creating an AWS Lambda function in Node.js. I want to use Cloudwatch `GetMetricWidgetImage` API to get the dashboard snapshot but seems like I am having trouble with it. Below is my code which I have written not getting any proper response. The code is executing till hello1 and the response I am getting is null.

```js
console.log('Loading function');

const aws = require('aws-sdk');
var cloudwatch = new aws.CloudWatch({apiVersion: '2010-08-01'});

console.log("hello");

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) =>{
var widgetDefinition = {
    MetricWidget: '[ "AWS/IVS", "ConcurrentViews" ]',
    OutputFormat: 'image.png'
};

console.log("hello1");

cloudwatch.getMetricWidgetImage(widgetDefinition, function(err, data) { 
  if (err) {
    console.log(err, err.stack) ;                //error occured
    //console.log("hello2");
  }
        else {
            console.log(data.MetricWidgetImage); // successful 
            var response = {
                statusCode: 200,
                body: new Buffer(data.MetricWidgetImage).toString('base64')
                
    };
          console.log(response);
        }
});

};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couple of issues here.

First, make sure the lambda has permission to call GetMetricWidgetImage.

Then this is the way to get the `widgetDefinition`:

1. Open the graph in CloudWatch Console.
2. Click on the **Source** tab.
3. Select the **Image api** view and copy the code from there.

Use the code you selected like this (your region might be different):

```
var image = {
    "view": "timeSeries",
    "stacked": false,
    "metrics": [
        [ "AWS/Events", "FailedInvocations" ]
    ],
    "region": "us-east-1"
}

var widgetDefinition = {
    MetricWidget: JSON.stringify(image)
};
```

Then you need to await on the GMWI promise. Your lambda returns before the API responds.

```
const response = await cloudwatch.getMetricWidgetImage(widgetDefinition).promise();
```

Also, GMWI returns a buffer, so you should not convert to buffer again.

Putting it all together:

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
const cloudwatch = new aws.CloudWatch({apiVersion: '2010-08-01'});

const image = {
    "view": "timeSeries",
    "stacked": false,
    "metrics": [
        [ "AWS/Events", "FailedInvocations" ]
    ],
    "region": "us-east-1"
}

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) =>{
    const widgetDefinition = {
        MetricWidget: JSON.stringify(image)
    };
    
    const response = await cloudwatch.getMetricWidgetImage(widgetDefinition).promise();
    
    return {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: response.MetricWidgetImage.toString('base64')
    }
};
```